# Electrochemical characterization of benzenesulfonamide

Tags: electrochemistry

I'm trying to elucidate current peaks for benzenesulfonamide, using an acetic acid-sodium acetate 0.1M buffer at pH 5.5 as electrolyte. When doing cyclic voltammetry, I get a voltammogram similar to the platinum (Electroanalytical Chemistry and lnterfacial Electrochemistry, 43 (1973) 9-36), because I use platinum as a working electrode. So, I can not see any current peak related to benzenesulfonamide, and I have not found any article related to this. I've been thinking about using a glassy carbon electrode instead of platinum.

Answer (score 2):

I'd change the solvent to acetonitrile (don't forget the quarternary ammonium salt) and give a glassy carbon electrode a try.

It should be possible to observe the (irreversible) reduction of the sulfonamide.

And once you have optimized the conditions, please perform a final run with ferrocene as an internal reference.

---

**Edit**:
Let me explain the last suggestion. The literature is full of electrochemical data of organic compounds measured in non-aqueous solvents, mostly acetonitrile.

It was once common (bad) practise to report the potentials vs **SCE** (saturated calomel electrode), although the latter, an aqueous(!) reference electrode, was atually **never** used in the measurement. Often rather exotic conditions plus a shaky conversion of data turned good experimental work into a pile of data of limited value.

Using an internal standard is the obvious solution to obtain solvent-independent electrochemical data for publication.

Note that the use of ferrocene as such a standard isn't my idea! It was originally proposed by [GRITZER and KUTA in *Pure Appl. Chem.*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1351/pac198456040461) and is a IUPAC recommendation nowadays.